# I need to give users to MySQL Views and Stored Routines, but not the underlying tables

Tags: mysql

I have a database with multiple schemas.  One of these schemas contains some data that needs to remain hidden from the other schemas while allowing limited access to other data.  The intent is to only make the data accessible via Views and Stored Routines.  
I'm using MySQL 5.7.33 on an Ubuntu server and MySQL Workbench 8.0 on Windows.  
My question is, how do I set up the schema to make views, etc. accessible, but not the tables.  
I've given users the following permissions on the restricted schema.  
[image: User Permissions]  
And the CREATE statement for the view begins:

```
CREATE 
ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
DEFINER = `DBA`@`%` 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `CommonData`.`VW_SystemProperty` AS ...
```

When I run a select on the view I get the error:  
Error Code: 1142. SELECT command denied to user '' for table 'VW_SystemProperty'  
What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try to grant `SELECT` permission on views and `EXECUTE` permission on stored procedures?

Comment: Yes, that works.  The problem is, I would need to do it on each view/proc.  I'm looking for a way to give access to all views/procs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you cannot grant privileges using wildcards in the procedure or view names, you can use the following script to generate the `GRANT` statements.
This is just a technique to save some effort and avoid errors.

```sql
select
    CONCAT('GRANT SELECT ON `CommonData`.`', t.TABLE_NAME, '` to user;') as GrantStatement
from
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
where
    t.TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW'
    and t.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'CommonData'
    AND t.TABLE_NAME like 'VW[_]%'
```

Once generated, the statements will need to be run manually.

Of course, you can add/remove restrictions in the `WHERE` clause according to your requirements.

A similar approach can be followed for stored procedures:

```sql
select
    CONCAT('GRANT EXECUTE ON `CommonData`.`', r.SPECIFIC_NAME, '` to user;') as GrantStatement
from
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES r
where
    r.ROUTINE_CATALOG = 'CommonData'
    and r.ROUTINE_NAME like 'usp%'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can grant to all procedures or all procedures in a given schema this way:

```
mysql> grant execute on test.* to 'root'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Strangely, the optional `PROCEDURE` keyword for the object type does not support wildcards in the procedure name.

```
mysql> grant execute on procedure test.* to 'root'@'localhost';
ERROR 1144 (42000): Illegal GRANT/REVOKE command; please consult the manual to see which privileges can be used
```

But you can use this keyword if you grant to a specific procedure by name.

```
mysql> grant execute on procedure test.foo to 'root'@localhost;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

The only wildcard for table names or view names is `*`. You can't use other wildcards like `%` or `_` in table names or view names.

In MySQL 5.x, you could use wildcards in schema names, but this is now deprecated, because it's a potential security weakness.

Comment: Although I agree with you @BillKarwin I did notice that the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html#grant-routine-privileges) mentions that "The ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE ROUTINE, EXECUTE, and GRANT OPTION privileges apply to stored routines (procedures and functions). They can be granted at the global and database levels."

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the answer above to improve it.